Is there a way to "kill' a thread and make it run again?
I write a project in Python and I use tk.raise and when I get to the multiusers chat frame I start threading, sending messages to all clients. But when I go back to another frame and try to use it code crashes because threading still works I need to stop the threading when I exit the chat and then when the user wants to chat again run the threading. how do I fix it?
class chat(tk.Frame):
    last_recived_messege=None
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        imgpath = "C:/cyberproject/pic/pic11.png"  # Make sure the path is correct
        self.background_image = tk.PhotoImage(file=imgpath)
        bg_label = tk.Label(self, image=self.background_image)
        bg_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)  # Set the label size to match the frame size

        tk.Label(self, text='Enter Your Name Here! ', font=("arial", 13, "bold")).pack()
        self.name_widget = tk.Entry(self, width=20, font=("arial", 13))
        self.name_widget.pack()
        tk.Button(self, text="Join", width=10, command=self.on_join).pack()

        tk.Label(self, text='Enter Your Message Here!', font=("arial", 20, "bold")).pack()
        self.enter_text_widget = tk.Text(self, width=50, height=10, font=("arial", 12))
        self.enter_text_widget.pack()
        self.enter_text_widget.bind('<Return>', self.on_enter_key_pressed)

        tk.Label(self, text='Chat Box', font=("arial", 12, "bold")).pack()
        self.chat_transcript_area = tk.Text(self, width=60, height=10, font=("arial", 12))
        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, command=self.chat_transcript_area.yview, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self.chat_transcript_area.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.chat_transcript_area.bind('<KeyPress>', lambda e: 'break')
        self.chat_transcript_area.pack()
        scrollbar.pack()
        back_button = ttk.Button(self, text="Go Back To Main Menu", command=self.go_back_to_main_menu,
                                 style="Green.TButton")
        back_button.place(x=3, y=3)
        # self.listen_for_incoming_messages_in_a_thread()
    def on_join(self):
        if len(self.name_widget.get()) == 0:
            messagebox.showerror(
                "Enter your name", "Enter your name to send a message")
            return
        self.name_widget.config(state='disabled')
        myclient.send_to_server_chat(("joined:" + self.name_widget.get()).encode('utf-8'))
        self.start_listening()

    def on_enter_key_pressed(self, event):
        if len(self.name_widget.get()) == 0:
            messagebox.showerror("Enter your name", "Enter your name to send a message")
            return
        self.send_chat()

    # def listen_for_incoming_messages_in_a_thread(self):
    #     thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive_message_from_server,args=(None,))  # Create a thread for the send and receive in same time
    #     thread.start()

    def start_listening(self):
        # Start listening for incoming messages in a separate thread
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive_message_from_server)
        thread.start()
    # function to recieve msg
    def receive_message_from_server(self):

        while True:
            buffer = myclient.recive_from_server_chat()
            if not buffer:
                break
            message = buffer.decode('utf-8')
            if "joined" in message:
                user = message.split(":")[1]
                message = user + " has joined"
                self.chat_transcript_area.insert('end', message + '\n')
                self.chat_transcript_area.yview(END)
            else:
                self.chat_transcript_area.insert('end', message + '\n')
                self.chat_transcript_area.yview(END)

        myclient.client_socket.close()

    def send_chat(self):
        senders_name = self.name_widget.get().strip() + ": "
        data = self.enter_text_widget.get(1.0, 'end').strip()
        message = (senders_name + data).encode('utf-8')
        self.chat_transcript_area.insert('end', message.decode('utf-8') + '\n')
        self.enter_text_widget.delete(1.0, "end")
        self.chat_transcript_area.yview(END)
        msg = message.decode('utf-8')
        myclient.send_to_server(msg, '3')
        self.enter_text_widget.delete(1.0, "end")
        return 'break'

    def go_back_to_main_menu(self):
        self.controller.show_frame(main_menu)

I tried using Event but couldn't quite understand it, and the code crashed when I tried it.

It is better to provide the error traceback when it crashes.

If myclient.recive_from_server_chat() is a blocking function, then it is hard to terminate the thread even Event() is used because the checking of Event() will be executed after myclient.recive_from_server_chat() returns.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Lia smith. How did you exit chat? You had one in the on_part() function?

In line 39, you cannot use self.start_listening() when you or the user join the channel  because connection is alreay established.
